# Git & Github Workflow, update sub trees with parent changes

Tags: git, codeigniter, github

I have a project called "TestProject".. this project is hosted on github as a private repo. This project repo will be pushed to several different servers/folders and modified according to the customers needs.

The core project uses CodeIgniter framework and the core functionality is the same. However views, configs, assets (css, js, images) change from site to site.

How can i deploy updates to each of my sites while retaining the changes from the css/js/images

Example:
TestProject has two new sites: ShopGilbert and GGG. Right now i clone TestProject into a new folder, change the branch to a new branch called shopgilbert and then make changes to shopgilbert and push the changes. However if i make a core function update to TestProject, how can i get that change to reflect down through all sub projects that are a child of that branch without having to copy/paste or worry about overwriting my views/css/js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for Git Submodules:

http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2011/09/managing-codeigniter-packages-with-git-submodules

Comment: Excellent - I've been looking for that, since I've just been downloading external assets/libraries when a new version comes out. Thanks!

Comment: thats not what im looking for.  I updated question with a bit more detail